# Typescript dynamic type based on array value

Tags: typescript

What is the correct `interface IMyClass` which would fulfill the requirements?

```
interface IMyClass  {
    params: any
    chooseParam: Function
}

class MyClass implements IMyClass {
    params = ['min', 'max']

    chooseParam = (oneOfParams) => {   
        return oneOfParams === "min" ? "something" : "something2" // <- I want to intellisense to say me that oneOfParams = "min" | "max"
    }
}

//usage
const a = new MyClass()
a.chooseParam("min")    // <- I want to intellisense here "min" | "max"
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkCeBhANnAZwOWQG8BYAKBJIAc4o4BbAgLmThEypuQQAsA9oIIQACg2bsAYgFcQCMMEEgqAXypUE%20Isix5CxYE1q4ITCOGIYcO4hWo16jFsgC8yANoByJqG8ANMi%20cAAe3gC6HMQIKgRgmo4kAsKiEi7uyAAUKhAA8jDpzGwcXACU7gB8ZDQA9LXIADwAtGjIAO6cYMhggsigkLi4wKIgosj80CgARH4g08gAPsizYdM8vDRQEGCyUCDIuQVFrm5nK3MLAPw9ULIo7PC4ohskGpTvVPWyBHAA5hAtHFunBMiAIO09LZDFkylQ4AA6FIicSSJhZWagaYVOoNFptTrgHp9AYQIYjSzjSbbC5YpYXNZAA)

Answer (score 0):

Does `params` have to part of the interface? Looks like it's just an argument to `chooseParam`. I'd do something like this:

```
enum ParamOption {
    Min = 'min',
    Max = 'max'
}

interface IMyClass  {
    chooseParam: Function
}

class MyClass implements IMyClass {

    chooseParam = (oneOfParams: ParamOption) => {
        return oneOfParams === ParamOption.Min ? true : false
    }
}

//usage
const a = new MyClass()
a.chooseParam(ParamOption.Min)
```

Comment: I want to create multiple classes implementing `IMyClass`, thus I need to define clear interface. This doesn''t help me much.

Answer (score 0):

COnsider this example:

```js
interface IMyClass {
    params: readonly [string, string]
    chooseParam: Function
}

class MyClass implements IMyClass {
    params = ['min', 'max'] as const

    chooseParam = (oneOfParams: this['params'][number]) => {
        return oneOfParams === "min" ? true : false
    }
}

const a = new MyClass()

a.chooseParam('max')
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wybexw)

`this['params'][number]` - obtains a union of all values in `params`

> Is there any way to define the type of function chooseParam inside interface IMyClass instead of Function type

Sure, if you want to type a function, please see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#functions) and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions).
In general, your interface should look like this:

```js
type Tuple = ['min', 'max']

interface IMyClass {
    params: Tuple
    chooseParam: (param: Tuple[number]) => boolean;
}

class MyClass implements IMyClass {
    params: Tuple = ['min', 'max']

    chooseParam = (oneOfParams: Tuple[number]) => {
        return oneOfParams === "min" ? true : false
    }
}

const a = new MyClass()

a.chooseParam('max')
```

However, it can be better. As far as I understood `['min', 'max']` is a static value which is not changed across app life cycle. If it is true it might be a good idea to move `params` out of a scope of `MyClass`.

```js
const Params = ['min', 'max'] as const;

type Params = typeof Params;

interface IMyClass {
    chooseParam: (param: Params[number]) => boolean;
}

class MyClass implements IMyClass {
    chooseParam = (oneOfParams: Params[number]) => {
        return oneOfParams === "min" ? true : false
    }
}

const a = new MyClass()

a.chooseParam('max')
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to define the type of function `chooseParam` inside interface `IMyClass` instead of `Function` type?